# Looking to delete named range2 when all values in named range1 are equal to “N/A” VBA Application.WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba, count, delete-row, countif

We are looking to delete an entire section of rows (named range  “Remove_Allowances_Credits”)  when all values in the section (named range "Allowances_Credits_Range") are equal to “N/A”.
For example, we are looking to delete rows 156:171 when each value in C161:C170 equal “N/A”. How do I use application.worksheetFunction count and countif to accomplish this?

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range")) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range", "n/a")) Then

    Workbooks(PharmacyPricingGuarantees2).Sheets("Pharmacy Pricing Guarantees").Range("Remove_Allowances_Credits").Delete
End If
```

I am getting an Error 1004

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range")) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range", "n/a")) Then

    Workbooks(PharmacyPricingGuarantees2).Sheets("Pharmacy Pricing Guarantees").Range("Remove_Allowances_Credits").Delete
End If
```

To delete the named range "Remove_Allowances_Credits" 
I am getting an error 1004

Comment: Count only has one argument, looks like you need COUNTIF.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the rows, clear the values, or delete the named range?

Comment: I am trying to delete the named range "Remove_Allowances_Credits") which is equal to rows 156:171.

Comment: The answer provided by DavidN resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTA(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range")) = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("Allowances_Credits_Range"), "#N/A")) Then

    Workbooks(PharmacyPricingGuarantees2).Sheets("Pharmacy Pricing Guarantees").Range("Remove_Allowances_Credits").Delete

End If
```

Firstly, you want to use `COUNTA` instead of `COUNT` for the first part.  `COUNT` only counts numerical values.  `COUNTA` counts all non-empty values (including #N/A).

Secondly, you want to use the `COUNTIF` function to count values = #N/A.

Comment: Thank you! This did it! I am new to VBA and cannot wait to become better at it and contribute to this awesome community.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, so I added a few different methods.

```
Sub Examples()
    'Might need to change Workbook reference to PharmacyPricingGuarantees2?
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Pharmacy Pricing Guarantees")
    If ws.Range("Allowances_Credits_Range").Cells.Count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("Allowances_Credits_Range"), "n/a") Then
        ws.Range("Remove_Allowances_Credits").ClearContents  '<-- Clear the values?
        ws.Range("Remove_Allowances_Credits").EntireRow.Delete '<-- Delete the rows?
        ThisWorkbook.Names("Remove_Allowances_Credits").Delete '<-- Delete the named range?
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This community of contributors is incredible. Thank you for your efforts and help.